# Group-based Access to S3 Buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

**TL;DR:** I need to structure my data architecture in S3 such that I am within the S3 bucket quotas (100 bucket maximum by default as of Nov 2020), but simultaneously restrict access to files for different groups, and further restrict access between sub-groups. Is there a programmatic solution to achieve this?

I am developing an app where there is a need to restrict access to an organization's stored files and content based on their organization identity/group/role. However, within that organization, further access restriction based on sub-group is required. An example is described below.

### Desired Use Case

Pet Users are all pets, but they differ by which type of pet they are. They are further differentiated by their breeds. I do not want cats to be able to access any other pet type's files, and they can only access the cats directory/bucket. Additionally, breed-specific folders should only be accessible to members of that breed.

Example: Tabby cats can access `Cats/` and `Cats/TabbyCats`, but not `Dogs/` or `Cats/CalicoCats`.

### The Problem

Pet types well exceed over 100 in this example. Thus, they would surpass the 100 bucket quota in S3. I don't think it's feasible for each pet type to have its own bucket. The quote can be increased to 1000, but that incurs additional costs and still does not scale well for the purpose of my application.

Additionally, Cognito User Pools are restricted to 10,000 groups/user-pool as of Nov 2020. While this seems like plenty, it does not scale for the use case. The following are the permutations I've thought of and their respective problems (I have left out permutations that are too similar to ones already mentioned with the same issues):

- **2 Groups, {Pet Type}/{Pet Breed}, with 1 Bucket/Pet Type - Example: `Dog`, `Weenie Dog` groups. The `Dog` group gives access to `Dog/` and `Weenie Dog` gives access to `Dog/WeenieDog` with attached IAM roles that grant access to respective buckets/directories.** This one is likely the least scalable permutation. It would quickly consume the group per user pool quota as well as the bucket quota.
  [image: 2 Groups, 1 Bucket/Pet-Type]
- **1 Group, {Pet Breed}, with Buckets categorized based on application resources - Example: `Weenie Dog` group gives access to `{Bucket}/Dog/` and `{Bucket}/Dog/WeenieDog`.** This solution fixes the bucket quota issue but does not solve the scalability issues with Cognito user groups.
  [image]

### Question

How can I give programmatic access to certain user groups to different buckets or directories in S3? The solution does not necessarily have to involve Cognito user groups/IAM specifically, I am open to others, as Cognito user groups/IAM don't scale well. Are there any programmatic solutions?

**Other Resources Consulted**

[Restricting S3 resources based on a user's group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63905848/restricting-s3-resources-based-on-a-users-group/65026820#65026820) - Very applicable to my use case but still unresolved

Other questions I'd looked at here were unresolved or outdated.

Comment: Have you tried statement conditions in both IAM Role Policy and S3 Policy

Comment: @MahdiRidho I have considered this but have no idea how I'd make conditions based off of custom Cognito attributes. Groups and Object Tags don't scale well for my intended use. Did you have any thoughts on how I could use these?

Comment: I can answer and give a sample case if you implement sdk with federated identity for the user role. We will be mapping the groups from the cognito user pool into identity pool then set the policy condition with prefix to identity_group/identity_id -> ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud}/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1. using aws policies
2. custom authorization

Using the AWS policies

there is a way to allow/deny access to an S3 resource based in the resource prefix or resource tags. So you can be good with a single bucket, just the object key prefix can be built using identity  attribute or object tags (e. g. a list of allowed groups).

Advantage - this option looks simpler, because only native aws features are used and you don't need any other components. And the authorisation itself is executed by aws. Maybe good for simple rules.

However - the solution could be very rigid - once built for  specific set of requirements, constraints and assumptions, a new requirement could completely break the implemented logic. I'd consider it as a bad practice to put semantics into identifiers ( authorization into s3 prefixes)

> Is there a programmatic solution to achieve this?

2. custom authorization

You can mplement a custom authorization component.

Basically you can implement a logic which based on the requester identity and requested object will decide, if the user has access to the requested object and then return a pre-signed url (or not). Here yoy are putting the fine-grained authorization logic outside the policies. A use case for a lambda function.

Disadvantage is that you will have to implement and maintain an extra decision component.

Advantage is greater control and flexibility - it may use the resource or identity tagging or S3 prefixes too, but if the authorization requirements are changed then you don't need to change the object storage or the application itself. and just use something more flexible (e. g. authz logic not supported by policies, a DB with ACL objects,.. )

One of the most common and serious vulnerabilities in the cloud solutions are too widely open or incorrectly implemented user-defined policies. So if you can, keep the policies simple and effective.

Comment: This is a great response. I agree that the first option is rigid for the data structure and thus undesirable. I want to clarify I understand the second solution, because I like it a lot based off of the following understanding: Using an AWS API (gql/REST), I can query a Lambda function with a custom authorizer, which acts as a gatekeeper and sorting hat for which files a user can or can't access? Secondly, if this is correct, would I reject/accept user access based on a required, custom userpool attribute that each user has? Or is there a better means to reject/accept access?